# Change alternative rows of a diagonal in java?

Tags: java

My code as it stands is

```
String spaces= "";

    for(int row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
        System.out.println(spaces+"");
        spaces += " ";
    }
```

which gives me an output looking like this

```
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
```

how would I display an output where the differ alternately...to look some thing like this?

```
  -\
   =\
    -\
     =\
      -\
```

Comment: Do a modulus and print based on even or odd

Comment: Use the modulus operator (`%`) and the conditional operator (`? :`), as in `println(spaces + (row % 2 == 1 ? "-" : "=") + "\\")`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

`System.out.println(spaces + (row % 2 == 0 ? "=" : "-"));`

This just checks the mod of rows and if rows mod 2 is equal to 0 (2, 4 etc) it will put an equals otherwise a dash.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String spaces = "";
String minus  = "-";
String equal  = "="; 

for(int row = 1; row < 6; row++) 
{
    System.out.println(spaces+"");
     if ( (row & 1) == 0 ) 
     { 
       spaces += minus  + " ";
     else 
     { 
       spaces += equal  + " ";
     }
}
```

Or if you want less code:

```
String spaces = "";
for(int row = 1; row < 6; row++) 
{
    System.out.println(spaces+"");
    spaces += ( (row & 1) == 0 ) ? "- " : "= ";
}
```

Comment: what is the variable x?

Comment: @user2387962 updated, should be your index, which  in you case is `row`